# Incorrect output in Depth First Search Implementation

Tags: python-3.x, graph, depth-first-search

Recently, I was looking at a code for Depth First Search in a website (https://brilliant.org/wiki/depth-first-search-dfs/). However their implementation is not completly correct.This is the code they posted

```
def depth_first_search(graph):
    visited, stack = set(), [root]
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)
    return visited
```

As you can see, the logic they applied is correct but they used set operation which changes the output everytime the program runs.

This is my complete program

```
graph = {'A': {'B', 'S'}, 'B': {'A'}, 'C': {'S', 'F', 'D', 'E'},
     'D': {'C'}, 'E': {'H', 'C'}, 'F': {'C', 'G'}, 'G': {'S', 'F', 'H'}, 
     'H': {'G', 'E'}, 'S': {'A', 'G', 'C'}}

def depth_first_search(graph, root):
    visited, stack = set(), [root]
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)
    return visited

print(depth_first_search(graph, 'A'))
```

Below are the outputs I get evertime I run the program

```
{'H', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'S', 'F', 'E', 'G'}
{'D', 'E', 'C', 'H', 'G', 'S', 'A', 'B', 'F'}
{'G', 'F', 'C', 'H', 'E', 'D', 'B', 'S', 'A'} and so on....
```

The reason for using set especially makes sense for the below line of code as we want the stack to store only the vertices that are unexplored.

```
stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)
```

So performing set difference operation achieves that objective.But it comes at a cost as mentioned above.So I tweaked the code a bit to avoid using set and make do with lists

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'S'], 'B': ['A'], 'C': ['S', 'F', 'D', 'E'],
 'D': ['C'], 'E': ['H', 'C'], 'F': ['C', 'G'], 'G': ['S', 'F', 'H'],
  'H': ['G', 'E'], 'S': ['A', 'G', 'C']}

def depth_first_search(graph, root):
    visited, stack = [], [root]
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.append(vertex)
            neighbours = graph[vertex]
            for neighbour in neighbours:
                # ensures we only add unexplored nodes to the stack
                if neighbour not in visited:
                    stack.append(neighbour)
    return visited

print(depth_first_search(graph, 'A'))
```

But I get a wrong result

```
['A', 'S', 'C', 'E', 'H', 'G', 'F', 'D', 'B']
```

The correct result must be

```
['A', 'B', 'S', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'G', 'F']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you're getting is a valid DFS order for that graph. There seems to be an unwritten restriction that a node's neighbors must be traversed in alphabetical order. With that in mind, two things:

First, you're adding the neighbors of a node to the stack in the order in which they're defined. But when you `pop()` off the stack, you take the *last* item off the stack first. That means you're selecting your nodes in reverse order. That's easy enough to fix by reversing the order in which you iterate over the neighbors:

```
for neighbour in reversed(neighbours):
```

Second, you haven't actually defined the nodes' neighbors in `graph` alphabetically. You either need to alphabetize the values of `graph` in the definition, or sort them before iterating:

```
for neighbour in reversed(sorted(neighbours)):
# or
for neighbour in sorted(neighbours, reverse=True):
```

Comment: Hey thanks again for the help.But I got one question, Is it really needed to alphabetisize the values of graph? If I look at the graph, its just a simple undirected graph where a node is connected to other nodes.So why would it matter whether I alphabetisize or not? The connections are gonna be the same anyway? Please correct me if I am getting it wrong.

Comment: There isn't one single DFS order for a given graph. It doesn't actually matter which neighbor is visited first at any step, as long as you follow one chain to the end before backing up and going down a different path. That can be done in a number of different ways, that will all result in different (valid) orders. You appear to be looking for a single canonical search order, and that result can be obtained by visiting nodes in alphabetical order, so I assumed that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Oh I see!Yes that's exactly I was looking for.I thought DFSs are only meant to be traversed in alphabetical order since most of the Youtube videos show traversal in alphabetical way.Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the initial code sample you have isn't intended to produce an topological sort, but simply to list all nodes that can be reached from the root. Probably important to note that it's not incorrect, it's just not supposed to give you an order.

Your code does basically what it says it should, and the output you're getting is as correct as the one you're expecting. As long as you just want a DFS that is.

I think what you're missing is that when you call `vertex = stack.pop()` you're forgetting that it always returns the last, (i.e. right-most element) and when you call `stack.append(neighbour)`, you're pushing the children onto the stack in order from left to right.

If you want a DFS that specifically goes down the "left-most" branch first then you need to reverse the order of the neighbours/children before you add them to the stack.

**EDIT**: I don't have enough rep to comment freely yet, but my answer is essentially the same as glibdud's. It seems like the issue you're running into is that you're applying additional restrictions in your head that aren't actually part of a basic DFS.

Comment: You are right! Actually from my perspective I was doing the basic stack operation as required in DFS where you push elements to the stack but only pop the last pushed element essentially following the LIFO rule.